# How to close previous element when clicking a button on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, children

I am trying to display an image and its description by clicking a button.
However, I want to close the previous box each time I click on another button. Can anyone please help me?

I've tried several method but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please add any relevant JavaScript code/HTML markup/CSS to your question as a [mcve] (particularly attempts you've made that didn't work that we can help debug). You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve. Each image is enclosed within a div element with a unique id and the CSS class image-container, the descriptions are hidden by default using CSS. Clicking a button toggles the id of that button to active and displays the corresponding photo and description.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Description</title>
    <style>
        .image-container {
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .image-container.active {
            display: block;
        }

        .description {
            display: none;
        }

        .description.active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="toggleImageDescription('image1')">Show Image 1</button>
    <button onclick="toggleImageDescription('image2')">Show Image 2</button>
    <button onclick="toggleImageDescription('image3')">Show Image 3</button>

    <div id="image1" class="image-container">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        <div class="description">Description for Image 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="image2" class="image-container">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
        <div class="description">Description for Image 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="image3" class="image-container">
        <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
        <div class="description">Description for Image 3</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function toggleImageDescription(imageId) {
            const imageContainer = document.getElementById(imageId);
            const description = imageContainer.querySelector(".description");

            // Close previously opened image containers
            const activeContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".image-container.active");
            activeContainers.forEach(container => {
                container.classList.remove("active");
            });

            // Toggle visibility of the clicked image container and description
            imageContainer.classList.toggle("active");
            description.classList.toggle("active");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```